# ostream iterator usage in c++

Tags: c++

here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::cout;

int main(){
     vector <string> me;
     string s;
     while ((cin>>s) && s!="end")
         me.push_back(s);

     std::copy(me.begin(),me.end(),
         std::ostream_iterator(cout,"\n"));



     return 0;
}
```

but here is mistakes

```
1>------ Build started: Project: stl_implementation, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  implementation.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stl_implementation\implementation.cpp(21): error C2955: 'std::ostream_iterator' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iterator(516) : see declaration of 'std::ostream_iterator'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stl_implementation\implementation.cpp(21): error C2955: 'std::ostream_iterator' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iterator(516) : see declaration of 'std::ostream_iterator'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\stl_implementation\implementation.cpp(21): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ostream_iterator` needs a template argument; use `ostream_iterator<string>` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I write this example.

```
// ostream_iterator example
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  vector<string> svec;
  string mystr;

   cout << "Enter the strings (Ctrl + Z to end):";
  while(cin >> mystr)
  {
    svec.push_back(mystr);
   }

  ostream_iterator<string> out_it(cout, "\n"); // be careful. not like yours
  copy(svec.begin(), svec.end(), out_it);

  return 0;
}
```

I complier it well.